# iPhone Objective-C socket communication with Socket.IO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I’m developing some sort of massive multiplayer board-game. My solution is node.js socket.io on server. I need solution for implementation some sort of objective-c socket which would communicate with socket.io for sending and receiving json objects as string. i won't use webkit with websocket. Is there any possibility? server will hold state of game, iphone clients will sending action to server and receiving changes on server back.

Comment: This question is off-topic; [questions asking only for recommendations of libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/2747593). OP, if you are still having this problem, then please start writing code, and come back when you have a more specific problem. Be sure to show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 10):

*edited 2015/03/19:* The Socket.IO guys created their own iOS library that supports Socket.IO v1.0+. Get it here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

---

*old answer*

I updated fpotter's socket.io library to work with version ***0.7.2 - 0.9.x***.
It supports sockets and XHRpolling.

https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc

Maybe you want to check it out.

Comment: Hi pkyech. I'm using your library and it works perfect with my iOS7 app. Now I want to connect once and manage the events from each viewControllers by NSObject to avoid too many connect/disconnect. Do you have any tutorial on that?

Comment: sorry, but no there isn't a tutorial for this.

Comment: I am adding [link](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) library in Xcode 7and  iOS 9. But after connection it is just giving me a response of `error code 400`. However if I am doing it in swift then it connecting correctly. Is this library of objective c is obsolete? @pkyeck

Answer (score 6):

Or have a look at [cocoaasyncsocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket):

> **CocoaAsyncSocket** supports TCP and UDP. The AsyncSocket class is for TCP,
>   and the AsyncUdpSocket class is for
>   UDP. Each class is described below.
>
> AsyncSocket is a TCP/IP socket
>   networking library that wraps CFSocket
>   and CFStream. It offers asynchronous
>   operation, and a native cocoa class
>   complete with delegate support. Here
>   are the key features:
>
> - Queued non-blocking reads and writes,    with optional timeouts. You
>     tell it    what to read or write, and
>     it will    call you when it's done.
> - Automatic socket acceptance. If you tell it to accept connections, it will call you with new instances of itself for each connection. You can, of course, disconnect them immediately.
> - Delegate support. Errors, connections, accepts, read completions, write completions,   progress, and disconnections all result in a call to your delegate method.
> - Run-loop based, not thread based. Although you can use it on main or worker threads, you don't have to. It calls the delegate methods asynchronously using NSRunLoop. The delegate methods include a socket parameter, allowing you to distinguish between many instances.
> - Self-contained in one class. You don't need to muck around with streams or sockets. The class handles 
>     all of that.
> - Support for TCP streams over IPv4 and IPv6.
>
> The library is public domain,
>   originally written by Dustin Voss. Now
>   available in a public setting to allow
>   and encourage its continued support.
>
> **AsyncUdpSocket** is a UDP/IP socket networking library that wraps
>   CFSocket. It works almost exactly like
>   the TCP version, but is designed
>   specifically for UDP. This includes
>   queued non-blocking send/receive
>   operations, full delegate support,
>   run-loop based, self-contained class,
>   and support for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Will this library work with Socket.IO out of the box?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest checking out the Apple documentation for streaming and sockets if you are planning on doing an native app. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html

Answer (score 3):

Check this out: https://github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa

Comment: This library doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, the git project doesn't even clone --recursive properly